# Why doesn't CollectionAssert provide any failure details?

Tags: c#, visualstudio.testtools

When I write the following code in a C# unit test:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 }, new List<int> { 1, 2 });
```

The unit test fails with the following details:

```
Fehler bei "CollectionAssert.AreEqual". (Unterschiedliche Anzahl von Elementen.)
Error at "CollectionAssert.AreEqual". (Differing number of elements.)
```

Now I wonder why the exception message is so unhelpful. It would have been easy to write:

```
Error at "CollectionAssert.AreEqual". (Expected 3 elements, got 2.)
```

Surely it must have bugged the developers of the `CollectionAssert` or their colleagues who had to use that class. What could be the reason for not providing details, especially during unit tests?

Comment: Simply guessing, they just simply did not have time? It might have been one of those features that simply did not make it on time, and was later forgotten. Regardless, there are multiple test-frameworks out there, such as XUnit or the still widely popular NUnit. Why not use those? Isn't finding the right tools, part of the proffession?

Comment: My question is not about alternative tools, it's about possible reasons why Microsoft might release such unhelpful code into the public, making the life of thousands of programmers unnecessarily difficult.